# iOS Facebook Share Dialog - "Post" button always disabled for open graph stories after latest Facebook app update

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

In the process of implementing the ability to share open graph stories from my iOS app using the Facebook share dialog, I have encountered an issue that only occurs when using the most recent version of the Facebook app (15.0).

Setting up and launching the share dialog works correctly (the custom object, image, and action show up in the share dialog), but the "post" button is always disabled and greyed out.

On earlier Facebook app versions, the post button is enabled and I can successfully post the story to my app's test user.

It should be noted that my custom actions and stories are NOT yet approved by Facebook. I am hesitant to submit for approval until I resolve this issue.

The code, shown below, is directly mirroring the Facebook example. My plist entries all match the settings in my Facebook developer account.

See screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg87Q.png

```
id<FBGraphObject> object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"redacted:event"
                                                                   title:title
                                                                   image:imgURL
                                                                     url:url
                                                             description:description];

id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
[action setObject:object forKey:@"event"];

FBOpenGraphActionParams *graphParams = [[FBOpenGraphActionParams alloc] init];
    graphParams.action = action;
    graphParams.actionType = @"redacted:is_attending";

[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action
                                      actionType:@"redacted:is_attending"
                             previewPropertyName:@"event"
                                         handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                 if(error) {
                                                     // There was an error
                                                     NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                 } else {
                                                     // Success
                                                     NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                                                 }
                                             }];
```

Comment: Pretty sure there is a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs for that already.

Comment: You're right, I had missed that. Thanks! For others, here's the link to the bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/350457275118420/

Comment: Make sure to subscribe so you get notified when something changed but also because we use subscribers as one parameter when we prioritize bugs